# 2 column jcombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I had quite a lot use for a multicolumn jcombobox, but have not yet found any nor managed to make my own.  I have tried several approaches found in web, but they have not worked.  Afterwards I read somewhere that those (old) does not work under current Java version.

I have managed to make my own so far, that the combobox has a table as dropdown list and I can select an item with mouse, but the goal is that when the user starts to type into the edit box, drop down list opens and cursor moves based on the text the user has written.  It seems that the events from e.g. `JTextField editor = (JTextField) comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent()` does not work.

Has anybody managed to make a two column combobox or have any ideas, how I could get the event when the user starts to type.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for autocomplete functionality (as I understand the question): it's supported in [SwingX](http://swingx.java.net) - and quite easy to use.

It boils down to implemneting a custom ObjectToStringConverter and configure the comboBox with an autoCompleteDecorator using that converter. Something like:

```
/**
 *  A converter which expects an item of an array type and returns
 *  a string representation of its first value. 
 */
public static class ArrayToStringConverter extends ObjectToStringConverter {

    @Override
    public String getPreferredStringForItem(Object item) {
        if (!(item instanceof Object[])) return DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION.getPreferredStringForItem(item);
        Object[] array = (Object[]) item;
        return DEFAULT_IMPLEMENTATION.getPreferredStringForItem(array[0]);
    }

}

// usage
// assuming an model with items being arrays 
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(arrayModel);
// the renderer supporting multiple columns, f.i. a table
combo.setCellRenderer(new TabularListRenderer());
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combo, new ArrayToStringConverter());
```

A complete working example (including the renderer and showing how-to force the width of the popup to be larger than the combo itself) is [TableAsListRenderer in my incubator section](http://java.net/projects/jdnc-incubator/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/kleopatra/java/org/jdesktop/swingx/table/asrenderer?rev=3379)

BTW: the autocomplete functionality is a standalone module, accessible via maven or manually downloadable from the [maven rep at java.net](https://maven.java.net/index.html#nexus-search;quick~swingx), you would want the swingx-autocomplete-1.6.4.jar (plus the corresponding doc/sources, if interested)

Comment: intereresting code description, from my possition only +1, sure I'll be reinvent the wheel, I'd (still) be replace JList with JTable and to override ListSelectionListener or MouseClicked

Answer (score 1):

> Has anybody managed to make a two column combobox or have any ideas, how I could get the event when the user starts to type.

you can to put `JTable` to the `JComboBox`, but by default you can to select only value from entire `JTables` row, not directly from `JTables Cell` (required additional workaround, not tried yet)

Answer (score 1):

i still searching for this answer too

here's i try so far..
i create Jpopup and put the Jtable in there..
then i use jlabel not jcombobox,
when user click jlabel, then the popup(Jtable) will show in that jlabel location..
when user select value on jtable, 
then the popup will dispose,
then the jlabel will show the result..

for your case, you can use jtextfield not jlabel

EDIT :
heres related question
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943313/get-value-from-jcombobox)

Comment: in Swing not possible to manage two popup windows (based on Popup) in the same time, then popup from JComboBox go away, is hidden, sorry no way, no simple workaround, still registred as Bug without proper fix (from Java4)

Comment: i not use combobox.. but 10000% i still agree.. its will contain many bug.. and no simple workaround.. thankz for correcting