# Get Value from JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jcombobox, listcellrenderer

I have `JComboBox` with 2 columns and I have `JButton`.  When I click the `JButton`, I need to get the result of the `JComboBox` selected value from first column and seconds column separately...

How do I this?

Also: how do I set the header of that JComboBox ?

The Code:

```
 public class Combo extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    private JButton button = new JButton();
    public Combo() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        combo.setRenderer(new render());

        add(combo);

        combo.addItem(new String[] {"1","bbb"});
        combo.addItem(new String[] {"2","ff"});
        combo.addItem(new String[] {"3","gg"});
        combo.addItem(new String[] {"4","ee"});

        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[]args){
        new Combo().setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==button){
            System.out.println(combo.getSelectedItem());
        }
    }
}
class render extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer{

    private JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label3 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label4 = new JLabel();
    private JLabel label5 = new JLabel();

    public render() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,5));
        add(label1);
        add(label2);   
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        String[] values = (String[]) value;
        label1.setText(values[0]);
        label2.setText(values[1]);
        if(index ==0){
            label1.setForeground(Color.red);
            label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        }else{
            label1.setForeground(Color.white);
            label2.setForeground(Color.white);
        }

        return this;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The question is two questions, and header is not a term that applies to JComboBox. You must give an example or context where the term is meaningful (but not as a part of the other question). The answers understandably don't demonstrate an ability to comprehend the second part of the question. You should edit the question to remove the second question, and delete the repeats of that additional question from the comments. Try looking for the second question separately, and if the question doesn't exist, ask it as a separate original post not as a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your items are arrays of strings, so you can print the selected item as follows:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((String[])combo.getSelectedItem()));
```

*EDIT:*

```
String[] selectedItem = (String[])combo.getSelectedItem();
for (int i = 0; i < selectedItem.length; i++){
    System.out.println(String.format("item %s = %s", i, selectedItem[i]));
}
```

Or shortly if all you need is the first item - `(String[])combo.getSelectedItem())[0]`.

Comment: really thanks a lot.. it works.. but how if i just need first value? i need the value separately

Comment: wo.. rily thanks a lot ^^.. but how to set the header of it? apologize for many request..

Comment: @JasonAmavisca what header ? :)

Comment: (i don't know how to call it) header of jlist/ list rendered from that jcombobox... or at least make index value = 0 not selectable

Comment: @JasonAmavisca not sure I understand. By header, do you mean the value displayed in the `JComboBox`? What do you want to display? You have a 2,5 grid panel is a renderer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18194/discussion-between-max-and-jason-amavisca)

Comment: i need to set header of item of jcombobox.. the header of first column= "NO", second= "Nama" ... heres i try.. if index=0 the border of jlabel will bevel raised.. else = the border will normal.. the problem is.. user can still select the value index=0.. (its the header)

Comment: @JasonAmavisca Avoid asking more questions in comments and rather post an new question on SO.

Answer (score 3):

To display the first value of the selected element, you could use:

```
System.out.println(((String[])combo.getSelectedItem())[0]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot it really help.. but can i set the header of it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be easier than the previous answers:

```
(String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
```